# VB.NET Converting Old_App_Code into multiple dll files

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, web, app-code

I've managed to convert a vb.net website to a web application project. Now I have my App_Code folder converted into an old_app_code folder. Also new dll files have appeared in the bin folder containing all of my old_app_folder .vb files, which is brilliant. The problem I have is I want to convert all of my old_app_code .vb files into individual dll files and not just one dll file. Can annyone give me some advise on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want a separate dll for each source file? Typically, all the code in a project is compiled into a single dll that you then deploy.  If you want separate dlls, you break your solution into multiple projects.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm updating an older project and thats how they did it. We went with the correct approach. One .dll file.